# How to restore online searches in unity after running commands in fixubuntu

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I run commands in fixubuntu.com to get rid of online searches but now I would like them back but can't find a way to reactivate them. I tried reinstalling unity-scope-home and unity-lense-applications but it didn't do it.

I also run command `gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes` and `gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `'all'` instead of `'none'`, using `gsettings set`.

Use `gsettings get` to show the current value :

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search 'all'
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search
```

So you can keep the disabled one sets by Fixubuntu script and get back remote content search feature.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install -y unity-lens-shopping
```

Reset:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search none
```

Remove this line from `/etc/hosts`:

> 127.0.0.1 productsearch.ubuntu.com

You can do that last bit by running this: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, removing the line from the bottom of the file, and saving with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then exiting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
 You may need to reboot for this to take effect.